# What permissions are needed in the stock pg_hba.conf file to allow a database role to get in?

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have found that setting up the pg_hba.conf file to be very tough.  Here's the common case that wastes my time.  What do I need to do?

First, setup a virtual machine at Amazon, Digital Ocean or a freshly installed Linux distro on my own hardware. I usually use Fedora or CentOS and then get Postgres via this method:

```
rpm -Uvh http://yum.postgresql.org/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm
yum install postgresql96 postgresql96-server postgresql96-contrib postgresql96-devel -y
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
systemctl enable postgresql-9.6
systemctl start postgresql-9.6
echo export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin:"$PATH" >> /etc/profile.d/postgresql96.sh
yum update -y
```

Just to rule a few things out, pop a hole in the firewall (this is dev -- it's OK)

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5432/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Create a database user

```
su postgres
createuser --interactive -W bob
<answer yes to make bob a superuser>
psql
ALTER USER bob PASSWORD 'whatever';
```

Edit `/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/postgresql.conf` and change `#listen_addresses = 'localhost'` to `listen_addresses = '*'`

Restart

```
systemctl restart postgresql-9.6
```

Now, here's where things always go sideways.

```
su postgres
psql -U bob -W
<enter password>
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "bob"
```

I know I need to do something in pg_hba.conf -- but what to write in there?  By default it says this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

I have tried this:

```
host all bob all md5
```

But that doesn't work.

I've tried

```
host all bob all ident
```

But that doesn't work.

I've tried to connect with pgadmin3 over TCP/IP from a remote box, but that doesn't work either, not that it would since it doesn't work locally.

In the end, I want to be able to login as bob locally and via pgadmin3 remotely.

**UPDATE:** Is there a webpage out there that cleanly explains how to setup the pg_hba.conf file for some typical use-cases?

Comment: Aside from `all` not being accepted in the IP address field, there's something missing here (`PGHOST` variable?) that causes `psql -U bob -W` to attempt a TCP/IP connection instead of the default Unix-domain socket connection, and so the `peer` auth method to be selected rather than `ident`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ident` is useless, and I don't know why it's still used in the packages. Please report a bug to pgsql-bugs about the RPM packages to complain that they default to `ident` on localhost tcp/ip connections.

`host all bob all md5` should be fine, though I'd usually write

```
host all bob 0.0.0.0/0 md5
host all bob ::/128
```

So... are you *sure* you reloaded PostgreSQL's configuration?

`pg_ctl reload`, restart the database, or `SELECT pg_reload_conf()`.

Alternately, could there be any earlier, not-commented-out, entries that match and result in masking your entry?

Comment: This works.  As an improvement, is there a way to avoid specifying bob's username in the conf file?  Maybe say "anyone with a password can login"?

Comment: @010110110101 It's right up in your quoted example, use the keyword `all` instead of the user name.

Comment: @010110110101 Your username confuses me. 0x05b5? 1461?